# How to get user permissions list from Magento database using a query

Tags: magento2

Query to get user permissions list in Magento 2.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/36902/admin-roles-role-type-table-column

I found related query in above link but permission column is missing.
Permission column exists in authorization rule table. So I am stuck with joining the table.

What is the query to retrieve all user permissions list from database?

Comment: Could you show us the query you are using currently, which you will have adjusted for your own use case? Please add it to the question using a code formatted block.

Comment: Do please also have a try at joining the permissions table, and when you show what you have tried, perhaps that will make it clear to readers what the issue is.

Comment: I created query but it retrieves 1000's of rows .May be JOIN is wrong in my query . My question is I have one user with user id 2 ,
if I run query, I need to get the permissions which the user has them.

Comment: Lovely. Please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76581201/edit).

Comment: SELECT ar.user_id,a.username,arule.resource_id,arule.permission,arule.role_id
FROM authorization_rule AS arule 
INNER JOIN authorization_role AS arole ON arule.role_id = arole.role_id
INNER JOIN authorization_role AS ar ON ar.parent_id = arule.role_id 
INNER JOIN admin_user AS a ON a.user_id = ar.user_id